# Docker run fail with ruby

Tags: ruby, docker

I have a little problem, when i run my container this:

```
docker run -it emails_request cucumber -t @teste_inserindo_email
```

It's ok.

But, when i run this:

```
docker run it emails_request
```

Where my @teste_inserindo_emails, is on my dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile .
RUN bundle install && bundle clean
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 80
RUN cucumber -t @teste_inserindo_email
#CMD ["cucumber", "-t", " @teste_inserindo_email"]
```

Not found, return:

```
$ docker run -t emails_request
irb(main):001:0>
```

Or:

```
$ docker run emails_request
Switch to inspect mode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's your question exactly? you can just run it manually by firing up a container with an interactive terminal from your image, and then run the commands you want, or have a script in the image (or mounted as a volume) and then pass the script as the entry command instead.

`docker run -it IMAGE_ID bash` (for running manual commands)

if you want to use a script instead, put an `ENTRYPOINT` script in your `Dockerfile` instead

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not express myself correctly. My idea was to just run the container, and it execute the command I need, not that I have to pass this command every time.

Comment: Yup, so you can go with my second suggestion, have a script that you build into the image, with the `ADD` directive in your `Dockerfile` (make sure you have made it executable with `chmod +x script_name`) , then tell the image to always start a container by with the entry command being this script (you can also specify this in your `Dockerfile` with the `ENTRYPOINT` directive).